# How to add 2 fragments inside the frame layout horizentally?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have 2 fragments, one containing recyclerview, and one containing details about the items inside the recyclerview.
I want my layout to look similar to the attached file.
I am using frame layout in the main activity xml file, but how do I insert the fragments inside the frame layout horizontally?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6elNy.png)

[image]

Comment: Please show your current XML code.

Comment: done, my first fragment has the recyclerview list items and my second fragment has the details about the items.

Comment: Your current XML looks like what I was going to suggest. What problems have you encountered with this layout? What results does it give and how does it differ from what you want?

Comment: For future reference, we prefer that you paste your code directly as text rather than a screenshot.